# When writing an R package, how should I include packages that are only required for tests?

Tags: r, package

I am writing an R package, call it X, and use package Y in a test, however package Y is not required for X to function.  Should Y be included in DESCRIPTION as a Depends, or should running the tests prompt the user to install the package?

I'm new to writing R packages, so please forgive me if this is obvious.

Comment: [In `Suggests`](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html)

Comment: "The ‘Suggests’ field ..... This includes packages used only in examples, tests or vignettes (see Writing package vignettes), and packages loaded in the body of functions. E.g., suppose an example10 from package foo uses a dataset from package bar. Then it is not necessary to have bar use foo unless one wants to execute all the examples/tests/vignettes: it is useful to have bar, but not necessary. Version requirements can be specified but should be checked by the code which uses the package." [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html)

Comment: I highly recommend reading through [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html).  I know it is long and can be very technical, but trust me, you will come out a better human.

Comment: *"if this is obvious"* ... there is a lot of confusion around the differences between `Imports:`, `Depends:`, and `Suggests:`; I *think* the actual under-the-hood implementation in R may have changed over the (long) years. I'm *confident* that the understanding and ramifications of the interdependencies is becoming more impactful as the number of packages on CRAN has grown over the last 5+ years. Either way, it's not "obvious" until you've been doing it a while, and the list of people who "do packages that much" (and well) is rather short.